# django querysets order by hour, minute and seconds

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have datetime object in models.py:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event time')
```

However, tournament may have flag for daily or weekly tournament (meaning it is repeating daily or weekly). So I would like to sort my tournaments by date, but ignoring **year**, **month** and **day**.
How do I order my tournaments by hour, minute and seconds? Is it possible with `order_by` or do I have to use raw sql?
I am using postgresql and django 1.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be to use a [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):

```
Tournament.objects.order_by(Func('date', function='"time"')).all()
```

It is PostgreSQL-specific though, because `"time"(column_name)` is one of its ways of extracting the time value from `timestamp` (casting with function-like syntax gets you the `time` part).

Comment: If you don't need the annotation, you can use the expression directly in the order by: `Tournament.objects.order_by(Func('date', function='"time"'))`.

Comment: Stubled upon this by searching the same ordering by, just wanted to add that it also works using sqlite. Although it may seem 'safer' to use something like : `order_by('date__hour', 'date__minute', 'date__second')`